# will_pagine undefined method, Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

Hi guys i have a problem with the utilisation of "Will_paginate"

That's my code in my controler :

```
def index
    @title = "All users"
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @users }
end
```

In my gemfile :

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'
```

undefined method `paginate' for ....

Do you have an idea of my problem ? Thanks :)

Comment: Did you bundle install?

Comment: Ofc, the code works on my lapton but not on my iMacs... It's very strange